# I want an auto hard refresh, not a simple auto refresh on my webpages

Tags: refresh, html

I know I can do a simple auto-refresh on some of my webpages (for example, the Home page of my site) by inserting a **meta tag** like

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
```

But after doing this I'm getting **really long page duration and session duration**. This is not realistic, and I think that the refresh does not "reset" the page duration counter, which I think should happen.

I guess this could be done with a hard refresh (Ctrl-F5 in Windows, Option+R in MacOSX), but I don't know if it is possible to force the refresh **to be a hard refresh**... or if this kind of refresh would serve to my purpose.

Comment: Well, most news sites do it. The homepage gets updated automatically with that refresh, showing new and updated articles if the reader is looking the home page. It's quite useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching for an answer to this, and it's all in the headers apparently.

You need to send a no-cache header, in php this would be:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

..and then just refresh as normal (javascript or meta).

Comment: Simon, that seems interesting. I've found though another solution through the webserver: We use Nginx, and we had the 'expires max;' parameter on our config file: that was the reason the page was always cached until users pressed Ctrl+F5. Deleting that line has solved the problem, but your approach is also very handy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this Method:

http://grizzlyweb.com/webmaster/javascripts/refresh.asp

It uses JS to the refresh and won't load the page from the browsers bf-cache so it should do what you require. It will also prevent entries from going into the users BF-cache so they will be able to use the back button correctly.